# Understanding forking within a for loop

Tags: python, operating-system, fork, system-calls, cycle

I'm learning multiprocessing in Python and I'm having some trouble visualizing `os.fork()` in my mind. I get the general cases that are thrown around the website, but I'm really having a hard time with this one.

Code is as follows:

```
import os

for i in range(2):
    pid1 = os.fork()
    pid2 = os.fork()
    if (pid1>0):
            print("A")
    if (pid2==0):
            print("B")
```

What I know is that 10 **A**s and 10 **B**s are printed. I've messed around with `print()` to find out what the process tree would look like, and I found that it matches my original idea, something like this:

[image]

This diagram represents behaviour of the code, where "type" just means if they came from either a "pid1" or a "pid2" line. Green circles represent the first iteration of the cycle, and blue cirles represent the second. Using this diagram I can account for the 10 **B**s printed, given that there are 10 processes of type 2 and each one of those prints **B**. Where I'm having trouble is in understanding which ones print **A**. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky problem. The easiest way to think about this is iteratively. The first iteration, how many processes do we have at the beginning? One. How many at the end? Four. Hopefully that's self-explanatory based on how `fork` works. Let's calculate how many "A"s should be printed when we start with one process in a single iteration.

Now, I like to think of `pid1` and `pid2` as "genes", which are sometimes carried over into the child process. For instance, in the first `fork`, the parent will hold `pid1 > 0`, the child will hold `pid1 == 0`. But the second `fork`, the next generation of children will "inherit" the same values of `pid1` as their parents because we don't modify `pid1` in the second `fork`, just `pid2`.

So, if we just look at `pid1`, how many of our 4 processes at the end of iteration one will have `pid1 > 0`? Only two: the original parent of the first `fork` and the second child of that parent from the second `fork` who inherited its `pid1` value. Therefore this iteration, only two "A"s will be printed.

Now, the second iteration, we start off with 4 processes, but the key is each one of those 4 processes will go through the same iteration described above. We already know how many "A"s will be printed per starting process. In a single iteration, one starting process ended up printing two "A"s, the second iteration will result in 8 "A"s printed if each of the 4 starting processes go through one iteration.

So in total, how many "A"s printed? Two in the first iteration, and eight in the second iteration. That means you should see 10 "A"s printed out for this program.

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much!! I had that very doubt! "If the parent's pid1=0 does it get carried over to children who leave pid1 untouched?". This makes perfect sense, and to think I spent hours thinking back and forth. Again, thank you, I'm marking this as the right answer.